Rendering a block programmatically does not render the twig template
I'm renderding a block:
    $bid = 13;
    $block = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('block_content')->load($bid);
    $build = $this->entityTypeManager->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block, 'default');
    return $build;

and using this output for a modal. The modal is displayed and also the block content. But the block is not rendered with a twig template . The theme hook 'block' and the standard template block.html.twig is not used.
How can I render the block the same way it is rendered when included on the site, i.e. rendered with the block hook and block.html.twig or overwrites by theme suggestions.
